# Why is there no underline feature?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

There is bold, there is italic, but what about underlining? Or strikethrough even? Coming from Microsoft Office or other areas of the Internet, not having a way to underline something or strikethrough irrelevant stuff seems weird to me, so where did the choice to not include it come from?

Comment: _"so where did the choice to not include it come from?"_ From the markdown language definitions.

Comment: Oops, overlooked that the question has been asked. Hmm. Well, there is strikethrough, so that's good enough for me I suppose.

Comment: Strikethrough *is not* supported. And thank the lord. Strikethrough humor is the gutter of genres, populated by the mentally infirm and the tragically pathetic. It is a weapon of mass lameness that brings down a pall over any conversation in which it is used. Its use should be made illegal. Users should be dealt with swiftly. Humane treatment should be avoided at all costs; they should be made to suffer as they have made everyone within sight suffer. They are the most base of animals. Disgusting.

Comment: Won't: [What do mean it is not supported?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296077/sandbox-archive/178145#178145)